# Citing author's full name in biblatex the first time it appears

Tags: biblatex

I need a citation command that satisfies the following conditions – similar to `\citeauthor` – and was wondering how to define it:

- If an author or a group of authors is cited the first time, then the
  authors full names are cited.
- If an author or a group of authors is cited the second, etc. time,
  then only the authors surnames are cited.

E.g.:

```
\citeauthor{cit:howson1983SciRea} were the first who discussed this thesis. … 
But today \citeauthor{cit:howson1983SciRea} refute this thesis.
```

This should result in:

> Colin Howson and Peter Urbach were the first who discussed this
>   thesis. … But today Howson and Urbach refute this thesis.

I already tried a solution to a similar problem:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand*{\citeauthortest}
{\defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
\defcounter{minnames}{99}%
\defcounter{uniquename}{2}%
\boolfalse{citetracker}%
\boolfalse{pagetracker}%
\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteindex{\indexnames{labelname}}{}%
\printnames{labelname}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

But I get a

> Package biblatex Error: Command '\citeauthortest' undefined

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [biblatex-dw styles](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-dw) have an option for this (`firstfullname`). I must admit that I could not have implemented it without Philipp Lehman, who delivered the code. But anyhow, it can be adapted for any style, I think:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl}
\listfiles
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[
  style=authortitle,
  backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\cbx@seennames}{}
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@nameseen}[1]{%
  \listxadd{\cbx@seennames}{\detokenize{#1}}}
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@ifnameseen}[1]{%
  \xifinlist{\detokenize{#1}}{\cbx@seennames}}

\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}{%
  \cbx@ifnameseen{#1#3#5#7}
    {\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
       \usebibmacro{name:last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \or
       \ifuseprefix
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#8}}
         {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#4}{#6}{#8}}%
     \fi}%
    {\usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}%
     \cbx@nameseen{#1#3#5#7}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\indexnames{labelname}%
   \printnames[citeauthor]{labelname}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{companion} were the first who discussed this thesis. \ldots{} 
But today \citeauthor{companion} refute this thesis.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I just took the code from `standard-dw.cbx`. The result looks like this:
[image: The enhanced <code>\citeauthor</code> in action.]

Comment: Your solution works perfectly well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\DeclareCiteCommand*` then the resulting command must also be suffixed with a `*` (see `biblatex` documentation). So in your case try `\citeauthortest*{citekey}`