# How to make biblatex treat the prenote like an author list?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to customize a biblatex citation style (adapted from biblatex-juradiss). I have the problem that in my text I use many \cite commands which have two or more authors given in the prenote, and I want them formatted similarly to the editors of the publication that is referenced. So if I write

```
\cite[Smith, John and Johnson, Henry][23]{biblabel}
```

I would like the output to look like:

*Smith* / *Johnson* in: *Editora* / *Editorb*, other bibliographical data, p. 23.

where Editora and Editorb are the editor's surnames from the entry in my .bib file, and "other bibliographical data" stands for whatever biblatex would normally output after the editors. Biblatex does the editor list nicely, and I'd like the authors to look the same.

Please note that the slashes are not in italics, so I can't just give the additional author names inline with the slash in the prenote. Also, biblatex uses whitespace in the editor list which is somewhat narrower than usual.

Comment: The issue with this is that the `prenote` argument would have to be passed to Biber from within the document, as Biber has to parse name list like these for `biblatex` to make sense of them - and I'm not sure how that would work. You could create a dummy entry for "Smith, John and Johnson, Henry" though like `@misc{smithjohnson, author{Smith, John and Johnson, Henry}}` in the `.bib` file and then do `\cite[\citeauthor{smithjohnson}][23]{biblabel}`. (If you go for this option, [biblatex. comfortable author citing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179239/35864) might be of interest to you.)

Comment: Instead of using `@misc` for the dummy entry `smithjohnson`, it might be better to create a new entry type `@person`/`@author` that does not appear in the bibliography even if cited and just holds the names. See also [Create a register of persons with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79342/35864).

Comment: Since last coming here, I have understood more of the issue. The core problem is biblatex's data model: I was going to use the prenote for displaying a list of authors. This would require to treat the data entry for the prenote as a name list, while it is a field, which has no index. The "obvious" solution should be to go to the data model definition and change the type of the prenote entry from "field" to "names", and then in the .cbx file copy the author format into that of the prenote field. Sadly, this looks like more than I can chew at this time, as submission date is drawing closer.

Comment: The problem with this approach though is that `postnote` and `prenote` are treated differently from the other fields by `biblatex`. While the standard fields are consumed (and digested) by Biber, Biber does not get to see either `postnote` or `prenote`, neither are the two fields mentioned in any of the data model files (so one would not be able to change the type from `field` to `name`; and it would be *necessary* for Biber to be able to see the `post`/`prenote` fields).

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is that name lists have to be parsed by Biber/BibTeX so they can be used properly. But the `prenote` and `postnote` field are local to the `.tex` file and are not passed to Biber for consumption.

So we either have to pass the `prenote` to Biber by means of writing to a temporary file, or we have to fake Biber's name parsing from within the document with `biblatex`/LaTeX itself.

The first method is can be implemented with limited extra work. The command `\formatasname` can be used anywhere to return a list of names as they would be written in a `.bib` file as `biblatex` would print them.

`\formatasname` writes the names it is given to a temporary `.bib` file and then cites them. In the process the names are parsed by Biber and are formatted just like other names.

Just be careful that you have no `.bib` file ending with `-formatnames.bib` in your folder. That file is automatically created by the code below and will be overwritten without warning.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nfblx@formatasname}
  {}
  {\printnames[labelname]{author}}
  {}
  {}

\def\nfblx@bibfile@name{\jobname -formatnames.bib}
\newwrite\nfblx@bibfile
\immediate\openout\nfblx@bibfile=\nfblx@bibfile@name
\newcounter{nfblx@name}
\setcounter{nfblx@name}{0}
\newcommand*{\formatasname}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{nfblx@name}%
  \edef\nfblx@tmp@cite{%
    \noexpand\nfblx@formatasname{nfblx@name@\the\value{nfblx@name}}%
  }%
  \nfblx@tmp@cite
  \immediate\write\nfblx@bibfile{%
    @misc{nfblx@name@\the\value{nfblx@name}, author = {\unexpanded{#1}}, %
          options = {dataonly=true},}%
  }%
}

\AtEndDocument{%
  \closeout\nfblx@bibfile}

\addbibresource{\nfblx@bibfile@name}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite[\formatasname{Humprey Appleby and Bernard Woolley} in:][13]{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]