# Biblatex format labelname

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, formatting

I want to change the format of `labelname` while using following citedas environment. The labelname prints out with `\textsc` format, which is intended for the bibliography in general. But not for the citedas environment. There I want to achieve that the author family name is only italic. For example like this:

EDIT: I've attached the necessary MWE

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
bibstyle=authortitle,% BIBLIOGRAPHY
citestyle=authoryear,% CITATIONS
hyperref=true,%
backref=false,%
sorting=nty,%
maxnames=99,%
isbn=false,%
block=ragged,%
dashed=false,%
]{biblatex}
% ==========================================================
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    TITLE           = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muko.bd1,
    MAINTITLE       = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Recht},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    SHORTHAND       = {MünchKomm},
    EDITOR          = {Säcker, Franz},
    SHORTAUTHOR     = {},
    VOLUME          = {1},
    TITLE           = {Allgemeiner Teil},
    YEAR            = {2015},
    ADDRESS         = {},
    EDITION         = {7},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@INCOLLECTION{fs.roxin,
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den „Retterfällen“},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
    OPTIONS         = {fshowcited},
}

@ARTICLE{jus2007.881,
    author          = {Jörg Neuner},
    title           = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal         = {JuS},
    year            = {2007},
    pages           = {881--888},
}
%   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
%
%
% === merged files ====
%
%
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\normalfont{#1}}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}%
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editor}{\normalfont{#1}}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}%\labelnamepunct% Kein Punkt zwischen Autoren und Werk
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Anfuhrungszeichen im Titel ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{{#1\isdot}}
% ==========================================================
% === kein S. bei @article & @incollection ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1}%
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================
% === @article keine Titel zitieren ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{}%
% ==========================================================
% === nur erste Seite zitieren @article @incollection ===
%
 \AtEveryCite{% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}% 
}% 

% ==========================================================
% === bei @article @incollection postnote in klammern fur seitenzahl ===
%
\AtEveryCite{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
}

% ==========================================================
% === bib driver @commentary ===
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === @commentary prenote position === otherwise use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430758/53779
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibcite]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% ==========================================================
% === @incollection herausgeber der festschrift nicht fett ===
%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

% ==========================================================
% === Incollection zitiert als option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \emph{\printnames{labelname}}%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \printfield{shorttitle}%
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}
% ==========================================================
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{commentary}{% TRUE
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}{}% FALSE
}
%
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{book}{% TRUE
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}{}% FALSE
}
%
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{article}{% TRUE
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}{}% FALSE
}
 % %
\AtEveryBibitem{%
\ifentrytype{incollection}{% TRUE
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}%
}{}% FALSE
}
% 
%==========================================================
\AtEveryCite{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% 
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  %\printtext[parens]{% Klammern um Jahr weg
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}
% ==========================================================
% =========== print 'Author, Journal Year, firstpage' =========
% ======================== 09.05.18 ====================
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
       \newunit
       \printfield{journaltitle}
       %\newunit% no comma between journal and year
}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
\newunit%\addcomma
\printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {%\setunit{%\postnotedelim}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}
% ========================================================
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
\ifentrytype{commentary}{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}{}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \ifentrytype{book}% === field
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}% === true
       {}%\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}% === false
        \ifentrytype{article}% === field
        {\usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
        }% === true
     {}% === false
     \ifentrytype{incollection}%
     {{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
     \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}
     \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
     }% === true
     {}% === false
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
    }{}%
    }
%
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
%
\begin{document}
%
% ==========================================================
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis,heading=bibintoc]
\tableofcontents% 
% ==========================================================
Test
\footcite[399]{fs.roxin}\footcite[Wendtland][§ 240 Rn. 63]{beck.ok}\footcite[888]{jus2007.881}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more about the name formatting in the entire document? There seems to be a type-specific formatting for the bibliography. What does it do for other types? How are citations handled? What should happen for other types?

Comment: The sledgehammer approach would place a `\begingroup\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph}%` before `\printnames{labelname}` and a `\endgroup` after it. But there should be a more elegant method once one understands the big picture of how your name formats are handled in citations, the bibliography and across entry types.

Comment: Actually the sledgehammer approach works quite fine :)

Comment: Of course it does, the nut is cracked, but it is not elegant or efficient. I'm afraid your edit let the whole thing get out of hand. The document class and font settings are not really relevant here... Can you reduce the example to the relevant stuff, please? And please upload the files to a plain-text sharing site (pastebin, GitLab snippets, GitHub gists) and not as a zip (zips could contain malware ...)

Comment: Is there any entry type for which you don't want the name in small caps in the bibliography? Currently you have type-specific formatting, but all types for which you have a formatting get small caps.

Comment: As far as the family name is concerned all should be small caps and bold. But for example with the type incollection I want the author of a specific „article“ in the collection in small caps and bold. The editor of the complete collection shouldn’t be in bold only the family name should be in small caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easiest if you change the logic for your name formats a bit. As in [Biblatex tabular bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443875/35864) I suggest you go with

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\AtEveryCite{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph}%
}
```

instead of the many `\AtEveryBibitem` blocks.

Then

```
\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \begingroup
            \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
            \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
            \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printfield{shorttitle}%
          \endgroup
          }}}
    {}}
```

should work. This is similar to the sledgehammer approach I suggested in the comments where one would place `\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph}%` in between the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`, but it is sensitive to changes in the name format for citations.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
bibstyle=authortitle,% BIBLIOGRAPHY
citestyle=authoryear,% CITATIONS
hyperref=true,%
backref=false,%
sorting=nty,%
maxnames=99,%
isbn=false,%
block=ragged,%
dashed=false,%
]{biblatex}
% ==========================================================
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muko.bd1,
    MAINTITLE       = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Recht},
    SHORTHAND       = {MünchKomm},
    EDITOR          = {Säcker, Franz},
    VOLUME          = {1},
    TITLE           = {Allgemeiner Teil},
    YEAR            = {2015},
    EDITION         = {7},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@INCOLLECTION{fs.roxin,
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den „Retterfällen“},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
    OPTIONS         = {fshowcited},
}

@ARTICLE{jus2007.881,
    author          = {Jörg Neuner},
    title           = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal         = {JuS},
    year            = {2007},
    pages           = {881--888},
}
%   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
%
%
% === merged files ====
%
%
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{#1}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{#1}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}%
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editor}{#1}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}%\labelnamepunct% Kein Punkt zwischen Autoren und Werk
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Anfuhrungszeichen im Titel ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{{#1\isdot}}
% ==========================================================
% === kein S. bei @article & @incollection ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1}%
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================
% === @article keine Titel zitieren ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{}%<-- this is a really bad idea
% ==========================================================
% === nur erste Seite zitieren @article @incollection ===
%
 \AtEveryCite{% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}% 
}% 

% ==========================================================
% === bei @article @incollection postnote in klammern fur seitenzahl ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% ==========================================================
% === bib driver @commentary ===
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === @commentary prenote position === otherwise use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430758/53779
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibcite]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% ==========================================================
% === @incollection herausgeber der festschrift nicht fett ===
%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

% ==========================================================
% === Incollection zitiert als option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \begingroup
          \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
          \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
          \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
          \printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \printfield{shorttitle}%
          \endgroup
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}
% ==========================================================
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
\AtEveryCite{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}{\mkbibemph}%
}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% 
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  %\printtext[parens]{% Klammern um Jahr weg
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}
% ==========================================================
% =========== print 'Author, Journal Year, firstpage' =========
% ======================== 09.05.18 ====================
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
       \newunit
       \printfield{journaltitle}
       %\newunit% no comma between journal and year
}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
\newunit%\addcomma
\printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {%\setunit{%\postnotedelim}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}
% ========================================================
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
\ifentrytype{commentary}{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}{}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \ifentrytype{book}% === field
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}% === true
       {}%\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}% === false
        \ifentrytype{article}% === field
        {\usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
        }% === true
     {}% === false
     \ifentrytype{incollection}%
     {{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
     \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}
     \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
     }% === true
     {}% === false
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
    }{}%
    }
%
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
%
\begin{document}
%
% ==========================================================
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis,heading=bibintoc]
\tableofcontents% 
% ==========================================================
Test
\footcite[399]{fs.roxin}\footcite[Wendtland][§ 240 Rn. 63]{beck.ok}\footcite[888]{jus2007.881}
%-----------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

[image: The relevant part of the bibliography entry now reads "(zitiert als: *Beckemper*, FS Roxin)" where the family name Beckemper is in italics]