# Biblatex: Two citation style for the same 'commentary'-type

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to implement a citation scheme for German legal commentaries.

Follwing a lead from [Biblatex format labelname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443837/biblatex-format-labelname) I have successfully implemented two citation styles which I call *commentary:mid* and *commentary:pre* (see MWE).

Now I need to address the bibliography. Here, the problem is that there are to basic bibliography styles:

One, which I call ‘commentary:editorname’ is implemented in the MWE, for example

> *Palandt, Otto* (Begr.):  Bürgerliches  Gesetzbuch  mit  Nebengesetzen.  79.  Aufl. München, 2019 (zit. als: Palandt/*Bearbeiter*).

The second one, which I call ‘commentary:title’, uses the title to identify the cited commentary, e.g.

> *Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch*, hrsg. von Säcker, Franz, Bd. 1: Allgemeiner Teil. 7. Aufl., München 2015,  (zit. als: MüKoBGB/*Bearbeiter*).

My question is: How do I implement two bibliography styles for the same type? Should I use another OPTION, as the decision which bibliography to use is made for each commentary individually? Or should I just define a second (sub-)type, e.g. ‘commentary:title’ and rework that declarebibliographydriver to fit my needs?

Thank you for your help.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}

@COMMENTARY{palandt,
    editor = {Palandt, Otto},
    editortype = {founder},
    YEAR = {2019},
    TITLE = {Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch mit Nebengesetzen},
    EDITION = {79},
    ISBN = {978-3-406-73800-5},
    PUBLISHER = {C.H. Beck},
    ADDRESS = {München},
    shorthand = {Palandt},
    OPTIONS = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muekobgb,
  maintitle  = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch},
  editor     = {Säcker, Franz},
  volume     = {1},
  title      = {Allgemeiner Teil},
  edition    = {7},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {MüKoBGB},
  OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{hdbversr,
  maintitle  = {Ver\-sicherungs\-rechts-Hand\-buch},
  editor     = {Beckmann, Roland Michael and Matusche-Beckmann, Annemarie},
  edition    = {3},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {VersRHdb},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: VersRHdb)},
}

@COMMENTARY{maunzduerig,
  maintitle  = {Grundgesetz},
  editor     = {Maunz,  Theodor  and  Dürig,  Günter},
  editortype = {founder},
  edition    = {80. Lieferung, Juni 2017},
  address    = {München},
  %year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {Maunz/Dürig},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: Maunz/Dürig)},  
}

@COMMENTARY{erfk,
  maintitle  = {Erfurter Kommentar zum Arbeitsrecht},
  editor     = {Müller-Glöge, Rudi and Preis, Ulrich and Schmidt, Ingrid},
  edition    = {16},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {ErfK},   
  OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{blah,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung. Mit FamFG, GVG und anderen Nebengesetzen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf and Lauterbach, Wolfgang and Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH},   
  OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{blah2,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung mit verschiedenen Editor-Typen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf},
  editortype = {founder},
  editora    = {Lauterbach, Wolfgang}, 
  editoratype = {continuator},
  editorb    = {Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  editorbtype = {editor},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH2},   
  OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,%
  sorting=nty,%
  sortcites=true,%
  maxnames=4,%
  minnames=4,%
  style=ext-authortitle-ibid,%
  articlein=false,%
  %innamebeforetitle=true,
  useprefix=true,%
  isbn=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Globale Änderungen
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Namen kursiv
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}

%Im Literaturverzeichnis Doppelpunkt nach Namen, kein Punkt
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

%  Schrägstriche zwischen den Autoren
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash} 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}

% ebd. kursiv
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\mkbibemph}

% Keine Ausgabe des Verlags
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}

% Keine Ausgabe des Ortes
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{location}}

% Namen sortiert als Nachname, Vorname
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
%\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

% kein Punkt nach Addendum
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{%
  \iffieldundef{addendum}%
    {\addperiod}%
    {}%
  }

% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
%  edition = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},%
%}%

% Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition von 'commentary'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\let\oldpostnotedelim\postnotedelim
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\oldpostnotedelim}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:stem}{\oldpostnotedelim\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:prefix}{\addslash\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpostnote{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mkpostnote}[1]{\mkpostnote@i#1&}

\def\mkpostnote@i{%
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    {\mkpostnote@ii}
    {\mkpostnote@ii()}}

\def\mkpostnote@ii(#1)#2&{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:prefix}%
    \cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{#1}}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:stem}%
    \cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{#2}}%
  }
\def\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{}
\def\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{}
\makeatother

% 'editortype' in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Doppelpunkt nach 'editortype'
\renewcommand*{\editortypedelim}{
  \ifentrytype{commentary}
    {}
    {\addcolon\addspace}}%

% Titel nicht kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{maintitle}{\normalfont{#1}}

% Kursive Schrift für Bearbeiter von Kommentaren
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary]{prenote}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addspace in \addcolon}%


% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/443837/biblatex-format-labelname
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\space}%
          \begingroup
          \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
          \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
          \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
          \printnames{labelname}%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \printfield{shorttitle}%
          \endgroup
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zit. als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mustertext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section*{Beispiele juristischer Kommentare}

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:mid}}
\cite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}.\footcite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}\\
\cite[(Armbrüster)§~138 Rn.~9]{muekobgb}.\footcite[(Armbrüster)§ 138 Rn. 9]{muekobgb} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah} \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2} \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2}\\
\cite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}.\footcite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}\\

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:pre}}

\cite[Bearbeiter][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}.\footcite[Bearbeiter][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}\\
\cite[Bearbeiter][Art.~20 Rn.~3]{maunzduerig}.\footcite[Bearbeiter][Art. 20 Rn. 3]{maunzduerig}

\printbibliography[type=commentary,title={Literatur (nur \texttt{commentary})}]

\subsection*{Implementiert ist das Zitierschema  \texttt{commentary:editorname}}

\subsection*{Implentiert werden soll das Zitierschema \texttt{commentary:titlename} wie folgt:}
\leftskip=15pt \parindent=-\leftskip
\emph{Erfurter Kommentar zum Arbeitsrecht}, hrsg. von Müller-Glöge, Rudi/Preis, Ulrich/Schmidt, Ingrid, 16. Aufl., München 2016 (zit. als: ErfK/\emph{Bearbeiter}). 

\emph{Versicherungsrechts-Handbuch}, hrsg. von Beckmann, Roland Michael/Matusche-Beckmann, Annemarie, 3. Aufl., München 2015 (zit. als: \emph{Bearbeiter} in: VersRHdb).

\emph{Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch}, hrsg. von Säcker, Franz, Bd. 1: Allgemeiner Teil. 7. Aufl., München 2015,  (zit. als: MüKoBGB/\emph{Bearbeiter}).\\

Siehe auch \emph{https://help.citavi.com/knowledge-base/article/byrd-lehmann-zitierfibel}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See partial answer here: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/519186/sorting-of-bibliography-entries>

Comment: I guess the main thing here is the `useeditor=false` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/519186/35864. It would even be possible to combine `@commentary:title` and `@commentary:editor` to one type `@commentary` that is only distinguished by whether `useeditor` is set to `true` or `false` (I'm not sure if that would be more or less user-friendly).