# Sorting of bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex

While working on [Biblatex: Two citation style for the same 'commentary'-type](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518949/biblatex-two-citation-style-for-the-same-commentary-type) I have created to separate bibliography styles / types for German legal commentaries, namely *commentary:title* and *commentary:editor*. The citation and the bibliography entries work as expected.

However, there is a sorting problem: Entries with type = commentary:title have to be sorted by title, whereas entries with the type commentary:editor have to sorted by editor.

Here is the current MWE demonstrating the problem. *Zivilprozessordnung* needs to be last, *Erfurter Kommentar zum Arbeitsrecht* needs to be first. Note that I will not only use commentaries, so any solution will have to apply to *article*, *book* and *incollection* as well.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}

@COMMENTARY:EDITOR{palandt,
    editor = {Palandt, Otto},
    editortype = {founder},
    YEAR = {2019},
    TITLE = {Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch mit Nebengesetzen},
    EDITION = {79},
    ISBN = {978-3-406-73800-5},
    PUBLISHER = {C.H. Beck},
    ADDRESS = {München},
    shorthand = {Palandt},
    addendum   = {(zit. als Palandt/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
    %OPTIONS = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{muekobgb,
  maintitle  = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch},
  editor     = {Säcker, Franz},
  volume     = {1},
  title      = {Allgemeiner Teil},
  edition    = {7},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {MüKoBGB},
  addendum   = {(zit. als MüKoBGB/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{hdbversr,
  maintitle  = {Ver\-sicherungs\-rechts-Hand\-buch},
  editor     = {Beckmann, Roland Michael and Matusche-Beckmann, Annemarie},
  edition    = {3},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {VersRHdb},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: VersRHdb)},
}

@COMMENTARY:EDITOR{maunzduerig,
  maintitle  = {Grundgesetz},
  editor     = {Maunz,  Theodor  and  Dürig,  Günter},
  editortype = {founder},
  edition    = {80. Erg.-Lfrg., Juni 2017},
  address    = {München},
  %year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {Maunz/Dürig},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: Maunz/Dürig)},  
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{erfk,
  maintitle  = {Erfurter Kommentar zum Arbeitsrecht},
  editor     = {Müller-Glöge, Rudi and Preis, Ulrich and Schmidt, Ingrid},
  edition    = {16},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {ErfK},
  addendum   = {(zit. als ErfK/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{blah,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung. Mit FamFG, GVG und anderen Nebengesetzen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf and Lauterbach, Wolfgang and Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH},
  addendum   = {(zit. als BLAH/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{blah2,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung mit verschiedenen Editor-Typen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf},
  editortype = {founder},
  editora    = {Lauterbach, Wolfgang}, 
  editoratype = {continuator},
  editorb    = {Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  editorbtype = {editor},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH2},
  addendum   = {(zit. als BLAH2/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{staudinger,
  maintitle  = {Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch},
  editor     = {Staudinger, J. von},
  editortype = {founder},

}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,%
  sorting=nty,%
  sortcites=true,%
  maxnames=4,%
  minnames=4,%
  style=ext-authortitle-ibid,%
  articlein=false,%
  %innamebeforetitle=true,
  useprefix=true,%
  isbn=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Globale Änderungen
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Namen kursiv (außer bei commentary:title)
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}%
    }%
  {}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{%
\ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {}%
  \mkbibemph{#1}}

%Im Literaturverzeichnis Doppelpunkt nach Namen, kein Punkt
\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

%  Schrägstriche zwischen den Autoren 
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addslash}% 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\multinamedelim}%

% ebd. kursiv
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\mkbibemph}

% Keine Ausgabe des Verlags
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}

% Keine Ausgabe des Ortes
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{location}}

% Namen sortiert als Nachname, Vorname
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
%\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

% kein Punkt nach Addendum
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{%
  \iffieldundef{addendum}%
    {\addperiod}%
    {}%
  }

% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
%  edition = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},%
%}%

% Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition von 'commentary'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  %\newunit
  %\usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary:title}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}% neu
  \newunit\newblock% neu
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \newblock
  %\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  %\newunit
  %\usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\let\oldpostnotedelim\postnotedelim
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{  
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:editor}}
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {}%
  {\oldpostnotedelim}} 

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:stem}{\oldpostnotedelim\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:prefix}{\addslash\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpostnote{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mkpostnote}[1]{\mkpostnote@i#1&}

\def\mkpostnote@i{%
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    {\mkpostnote@ii}
    {\mkpostnote@ii()}}

\def\mkpostnote@ii(#1)#2&{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:prefix}%
    \cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{#1}}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:stem}%
    \cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{#2}}%
  }
\def\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{}
\def\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{}
\makeatother

% 'editortype' in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor,commentary:title]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Doppelpunkt nach 'editortype'
\renewcommand*{\editortypedelim}{
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:editor}}
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }
    {}%
    {\addcomma\space}%
  }%

% Titel nicht kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{maintitle}{\normalfont{#1}}


% Kursive Schrift für Bearbeiter von Kommentaren und "in: "
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:title,commentary:editor]{prenote}{\mkbibemph{#1}\addspace in \addcolon}%



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Mustertext
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\section*{Beispiele juristischer Kommentare}

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:mid}}
\cite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}.\footcite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}\\
\cite[(Armbrüster)§~138 Rn.~9]{muekobgb}.\footcite[(Armbrüster)§ 138 Rn. 9]{muekobgb} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah}. \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2}. \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2}\\
\cite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}.\footcite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}\\

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:pre}}

\cite[Matusche-Beckmann][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}.\footcite[Matusche-Beckmann][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}\\
\cite[Mustermann][Art.~20 Rn.~3]{maunzduerig}.\footcite[Mustermann][Art. 20 Rn. 3]{maunzduerig}

\printbibliography[type=commentary:editor,title={Literatur (nur \texttt{commentary:editor})}]

\printbibliography[type=commentary:title,title={Literatur (nur \texttt{commentary:title})}]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use author, editor other other names for sorting, you can issue the options `useauthor=false, useditor=false,` for those entries. In new versions of `biblatex` it is possible to do that on a per-type basis

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[commentary:title]{useeditor=false}
```

Then you only need to make sure that the sorting scheme also takes into account `maintitle`, since you use that field extensively. The usual definition only takes `sorttitle` and `title`. A natural extension of the standard definition would be

```
\DeclareSortingTemplate{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{maintitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{maintitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}
```

In total

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage[%
  backend=biber,%
  sorting=nty,%
  sortcites=true,%
  maxnames=4,%
  minnames=4,%
  style=ext-authortitle-ibid,%
  articlein=false,%
  %innamebeforetitle=true,
  useprefix=true,%
  isbn=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions[commentary:title]{useeditor=false}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{maintitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{maintitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{volume}
    \literal{0}
  }
}


\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{%
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}%
    }%
  {#1}%
  {\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {#1}%
  {\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnameprefix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {#1}%
  {\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamesuffix}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {#1}%
  {\mkbibemph{#1}}}


%Im Literaturverzeichnis Doppelpunkt nach Namen, kein Punkt
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space} 

%  Schrägstriche zwischen den Autoren 
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}% 
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%

% ebd. kursiv
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\mkbibemph}

% Keine Ausgabe des Verlags
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{publisher}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{publisher}}

% Keine Ausgabe des Ortes
%\AtEveryCitekey{\clearlist{location}}
%\AtEveryBibitem{\clearlist{location}}

% Namen sortiert als Nachname, Vorname
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
%\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}

% kein Punkt nach Addendum
\renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{%
  \iffieldundef{addendum}%
    {\addperiod}%
    {}%
  }

% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
%\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
%  edition = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},%
%}%

% Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen
%\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Definition von 'commentary'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  %\newunit
  %\usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary:title}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}% neu
  \newunit\newblock% neu
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
  \newblock
  %\usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  %\newunit
  %\usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \printlist{location}%
  \setunit*{\space}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}%
  \newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\let\oldpostnotedelim\postnotedelim
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:editor}}
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }%
  {}%
  {\oldpostnotedelim}} 

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:stem}{\oldpostnotedelim\mkpageprefix[pagination][\mknormrange]{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote:prefix}{\addslash\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mkpostnote{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\mkpostnote}[1]{\mkpostnote@i#1&}

\def\mkpostnote@i{%
  \@ifnextchar(%)
    {\mkpostnote@ii}
    {\mkpostnote@ii()}}

\def\mkpostnote@ii(#1)#2&{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:prefix}%
    \cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{#1}}%
  \ifblank{#2}{}{%
    \blx@getformat\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{ffd}{}{postnote:stem}%
    \cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{#2}}%
  }
\def\cbx@postnote@stem@fmt{}
\def\cbx@postnote@prefix@fmt{}
\makeatother

% 'editortype' in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor,commentary:title]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

% Doppelpunkt nach 'editortype'
\renewcommand*{\editortypedelim}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:editor}}
    or
    test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}
    }
    {\addspace}%
    {\addcomma\space}%
  }%

% Titel nicht kursiv
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{title}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:editor]{maintitle}{\normalfont{#1}}


% Kursive Schrift für Bearbeiter von Kommentaren und "in: "
\DeclareFieldFormat[commentary:title,commentary:editor]{prenote}{\mkbibemph{#1}\space\bibstring{in}\addcolon}%


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY:EDITOR{palandt,
    editor = {Palandt, Otto},
    editortype = {founder},
    YEAR = {2019},
    TITLE = {Bürgerliches Gesetzbuch mit Nebengesetzen},
    EDITION = {79},
    ISBN = {978-3-406-73800-5},
    PUBLISHER = {C.H. Beck},
    ADDRESS = {München},
    shorthand = {Palandt},
    addendum   = {(zit. als Palandt/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
    %OPTIONS = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{muekobgb,
  maintitle  = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch},
  editor     = {Säcker, Franz},
  volume     = {1},
  title      = {Allgemeiner Teil},
  edition    = {7},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {MüKoBGB},
  addendum   = {(zit. als MüKoBGB/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{hdbversr,
  maintitle  = {Ver\-sicherungs\-rechts-Hand\-buch},
  editor     = {Beckmann, Roland Michael and Matusche-Beckmann, Annemarie},
  edition    = {3},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {VersRHdb},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: VersRHdb)},
}

@COMMENTARY:EDITOR{maunzduerig,
  maintitle  = {Grundgesetz},
  editor     = {Maunz,  Theodor  and  Dürig,  Günter},
  editortype = {founder},
  edition    = {80. Erg.-Lfrg., Juni 2017},
  address    = {München},
  %year       = {2015},
  shorthand  = {Maunz/Dürig},   
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
  addendum = {(zit. als \emph{Bearbeiter} in: Maunz/Dürig)},  
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{erfk,
  maintitle  = {Erfurter Kommentar zum Arbeitsrecht},
  editor     = {Müller-Glöge, Rudi and Preis, Ulrich and Schmidt, Ingrid},
  edition    = {16},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {ErfK},
  addendum   = {(zit. als ErfK/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{blah,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung. Mit FamFG, GVG und anderen Nebengesetzen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf and Lauterbach, Wolfgang and Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH},
  addendum   = {(zit. als BLAH/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{blah2,
  maintitle  = {Zivilprozessordnung mit verschiedenen Editor-Typen},
  editor     = {Baumbach, Adolf},
  editortype = {founder},
  editora    = {Lauterbach, Wolfgang}, 
  editoratype = {continuator},
  editorb    = {Albers, Jan and Hartmann, Peter},
  editorbtype = {editor},
  edition    = {74},
  address    = {München},
  year       = {2016},
  shorthand  = {BLAH2},
  addendum   = {(zit. als BLAH2/\emph{Bearbeiter})}
  %OPTIONS    = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY:TITLE{staudinger,
  maintitle  = {Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Gesetzbuch},
  editor     = {Staudinger, J. von},
  editortype = {founder},

}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\section*{Beispiele juristischer Kommentare}

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:mid}}
\cite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}.\footcite[(Ellenberger)§ 134 Rn. 14]{palandt}\\
\cite[(Armbrüster)§~138 Rn.~9]{muekobgb}.\footcite[(Armbrüster)§ 138 Rn. 9]{muekobgb} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah}. \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 287 Rn. 5]{blah} \\
\cite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2}. \footcite[(Hartmann)§ 286 Rn. 13]{blah2}\\
\cite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}.\footcite[(Bearbeiter)§ 1 KSchG Rn. 2]{erfk}\\

\subsection*{Kommentare mit Zitierschema \texttt{commentator:pre}}

\cite[Matusche-Beckmann][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}.\footcite[Matusche-Beckmann][§ 3 Rn. 15]{hdbversr}\\
\cite[Mustermann][Art.~20 Rn.~3]{maunzduerig}.\footcite[Mustermann][Art. 20 Rn. 3]{maunzduerig}

\printbibliography[type=commentary:editor,title={Literatur (nur \texttt{commentary:editor})}]

\printbibliography[type=commentary:title,title={Literatur (nur \texttt{commentary:title})}]

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I changed a few small things that caught my eye, but I didn't go through all of the code.

The redefinitions of `\mkbibnamefamily` did what they were supposed to do, but I would still recommend the slightly more standard way of writing them that I used here.

In theory

```
\ifboolexpr{%
  test {\ifentrytype{commentary:title}}%
}%
```

could of course be replaced by

```
\ifentrytype{commentary:title}
```