# biblatex hyperref enable hyperlink for the complete footcite

Tags: biblatex, formatting, hyperref

I noticed that my `\footcite`s which should be working with `hyperref` are not completely "hyperlinked". Only a part or sometimes even the space between word is hyperlinked and will refer to the correct entry in the bibliography. So sometimes it can be very annoying finding the hyperlinked part of the `footcite` which leads to the correct bib entry.

Any ideas how I can change it so that the whole `\footcite` as one is hyperlinked?

I've attached a MWE and pictures that show the behaviour.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
bibstyle=authortitle,% BIBLIOGRAPHY
citestyle=authoryear,% CITATIONS
hyperref=true,%
backref=false,%
sorting=nty,%
maxnames=99,%
isbn=false,%
block=ragged,%
dashed=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% ==========================================================
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    TITLE           = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muko.bd1,
    MAINTITLE       = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Recht},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    SHORTHAND       = {MünchKomm},
    EDITOR          = {Säcker, Franz},
    SHORTAUTHOR     = {},
    VOLUME          = {1},
    TITLE           = {Allgemeiner Teil},
    YEAR            = {2015},
    ADDRESS         = {},
    EDITION         = {7},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@INCOLLECTION{fs.roxin,
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den „Retterfällen“},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
    OPTIONS         = {fshowcited},
}

@ARTICLE{jus2007.881,
    author          = {Jörg Neuner},
    title           = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal         = {JuS},
    year            = {2007},
    pages           = {881--888},
}
%   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
%
%
% === merged files ====
%
%
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{\mkbibbold{%
  \ifgiveninits
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiveni}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}{\namepartfamily}{\namepartgiven}{\namepartprefix}{\namepartsuffix}}%
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\normalfont{#1}}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\normalfont{#1}}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat{maintitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\normalfont{#1}}%
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{booktitle}{\normalfont{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editor}{\normalfont{#1}}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}%\labelnamepunct% Kein Punkt zwischen Autoren und Werk
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === kein Anfuhrungszeichen im Titel ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{citetitle}{{#1\isdot}}
% ==========================================================
% === kein S. bei @article & @incollection ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{pages}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{pages}{#1}%
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================
% === @article keine Titel zitieren ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{}%
% ==========================================================
% === nur erste Seite zitieren @article @incollection ===
%
 \AtEveryCite{% 
  \DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{\mkfirstpage{#1}}% 
}% 

% ==========================================================
% === bei @article @incollection postnote in klammern fur seitenzahl ===
%
\AtEveryCite{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
}

% ==========================================================
% === bib driver @commentary ===
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === @commentary prenote position === otherwise use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430758/53779
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibcite]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}%
   \ifentrytype{commentary}{\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace\textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}{}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% ==========================================================
% === @incollection herausgeber der festschrift nicht fett ===
%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

% ==========================================================
% === Incollection zitiert als option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \emph{\printnames{labelname}}%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \printfield{shorttitle}%
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}
% ==========================================================
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}% Autoren in Kapitaelchen
%==========================================================
\AtEveryCite{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% 
  \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  %\printtext[parens]{% Klammern um Jahr weg
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}
% ==========================================================
% =========== print 'Author, Journal Year, firstpage' =========
% ======================== 09.05.18 ====================
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
       \newunit
       \printfield{journaltitle}
       %\newunit% no comma between journal and year
}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
\newunit%\addcomma
\printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewbibmacro{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {%\setunit{%\postnotedelim}%
    \printfield{postnote}}}
% ========================================================
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
\ifentrytype{commentary}{\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}{}%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}%
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
       \ifentrytype{book}% === field
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}% === true
       {}%\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}% === false
        \ifentrytype{article}% === field
        {\usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}\usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
        }% === true
     {}% === false
     \ifentrytype{incollection}%
     {{\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}}
     \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}
     \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}%
     }% === true
     {}% === false
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
    }{}%
    }
%
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
\makeatletter

% user-level command for printing tabular bibliography
\let\printbibtabular\printbibliography
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\let\bbx@printbibtabular\blx@printbibliography
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}{\blx@bibliography}{\bbx@bibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}
  {\def\blx@theenv{bibliography}}{\def\blx@theenv{bibtabular}}{}{}


% underlying macros
\def\bbx@bibtabular#1{%
  \blx@langstrings
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit@next}%
  % copy filtered list of entries to internal list macro
  \def\blx@do##1{%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}{%
      \begingroup
      \blx@getdata{##1}%
      \blx@bibcheck
      \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
        \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
        \listadd\blx@tempa{##1}}%
      \endgroup}{}}%
  \let\blx@done\relax
  \blx@listloop{#1}%
  % tabular output for each item in list macro
  \def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1}\\}%
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup
  \endgroup% this closed a goup opened by \printbibtabular
}

\def\bbx@tab@label#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setdefaultrefcontext{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \blx@initsep
  \blx@namesep
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
  \blx@anchor
  \csuse{bbx@tabenv@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \endgroup
}

\def\bbx@tab@item#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \blx@execute
  \blx@initunit
  \blx@beglangbib
  \bibsentence
  \blx@pagetracker
  \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@endlangbib
  \endgroup
}

% user-level command for defining tabular bibliography format
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibtabular}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{bbx@tabenv@#1}{#4}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#5}}

\makeatother

% sortname labels (a robust style should add provision for missing labelnames)
\newbibmacro*{sortname}{%
  \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\break}%
  \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
  \printnames[sortname]{labelname}}

% bibitem hook to suppress redundant sortname list
\newbibmacro*{omitsortname}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {}
    {\clearname{\thefield{labelnamesource}}}}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
% demo new tabular bibliography format
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                      L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
  {\usebibmacro{sortname}}
  {\usebibmacro{omitsortname}}

% add multiline labels in default bibliography format
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\usebibmacro{sortname}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0.3\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
       \nobreak\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedright##1}}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\usebibmacro{omitsortname}}
  \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}%
% ==========================================================
%
\begin{document}
%
% ==========================================================
%\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis alt,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibtabular[title=Literaturverzeichnis,heading=bibintoc]
\tableofcontents% 
% ==========================================================
Test
\footcite[399]{fs.roxin}\footcite[Wendtland][§ 240 Rn. 63]{beck.ok}\footcite[888]{jus2007.881}
%-----
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `\printtext[bibhyperref]` in the definition of `\cite` et al. I have refactored your `cite` bibmacro a bit, so it works a bit more smoothly. I have also applied all the other small corrections that I already put into your code in [Biblatex tabular bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/443875/35864). You may want to have a look at those as well

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
bibstyle=authortitle,% BIBLIOGRAPHY
citestyle=authoryear,% CITATIONS
hyperref=true,%
backref=false,%
sorting=nty,%
maxnames=99,%
isbn=false,%
block=ragged,%
dashed=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% ==========================================================
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    TITLE           = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muko.bd1,
    MAINTITLE       = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Recht},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    SHORTHAND       = {MünchKomm},
    EDITOR          = {Säcker, Franz},
    SHORTAUTHOR     = {},
    VOLUME          = {1},
    TITLE           = {Allgemeiner Teil},
    YEAR            = {2015},
    ADDRESS         = {},
    EDITION         = {7},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@INCOLLECTION{fs.roxin,
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den „Retterfällen“},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
    OPTIONS         = {fshowcited},
}

@ARTICLE{jus2007.881,
    author          = {Jörg Neuner},
    title           = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal         = {JuS},
    year            = {2007},
    pages           = {881--888},
}
%   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
%
%
% === merged files ====
%
%
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}%\labelnamepunct% Kein Punkt zwischen Autoren und Werk
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === kein S. bei @article & @incollection, nur erste Seite im Zitat ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{%
  \ifcitation
    {\mkfirstpage{#1}}
    {#1}}%
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================
% === @article keine Titel zitieren ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{}%
% ==========================================================

% === bei @article @incollection postnote in klammern fur seitenzahl ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
% === bib driver @commentary ===
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === @commentary prenote position === otherwise use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430758/53779
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{####1}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}%
     \ifentrytype{commentary}
       {\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace
        \textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
       {}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibcite]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{####1}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}%
     \ifentrytype{commentary}
       {\thinspace\thinspace\textbf{\addslash}\thinspace
        \textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
       {}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% ==========================================================
% === @incollection herausgeber der festschrift nicht fett ===
%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

% ==========================================================
% === Incollection zitiert als option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \emph{\printnames{labelname}}%
          \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
          \printfield{shorttitle}%
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}
% ==========================================================
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}% Autoren in Kapitaelchen
%==========================================================
\AtEveryCite{%
  \renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% 
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}
% ==========================================================
% =========== print 'Author, Journal Year, firstpage' =========
% ======================== 09.05.18 ====================
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
  \printfield{journaltitle}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
  \printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
% ========================================================
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \ifentrytype{book}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}
       {}%
     \ifentrytype{article}
       {\newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}}
       {}%
     \ifentrytype{incollection}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}}
       {}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}

\makeatletter

% user-level command for printing tabular bibliography
\let\printbibtabular\printbibliography
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\printbibtabular}{\blx@printbibliography}{\bbx@printbibtabular}{}{}
\let\bbx@printbibtabular\blx@printbibliography
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}{\blx@bibliography}{\bbx@bibtabular}{}{}
\patchcmd{\bbx@printbibtabular}
  {\def\blx@theenv{bibliography}}{\def\blx@theenv{bibtabular}}{}{}


% underlying macros
\def\bbx@bibtabular#1{%
  \blx@langstrings
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit@next}%
  % copy filtered list of entries to internal list macro
  \def\blx@do##1{%
    \blx@ifdata{##1}{%
      \begingroup
      \blx@getdata{##1}%
      \blx@bibcheck
      \iftoggle{blx@skipentry}{}{%
        \global\let\blx@noitem\@empty
        \listadd\blx@tempa{##1}}%
      \endgroup}{}}%
  \let\blx@done\relax
  \blx@listloop{#1}%
  % tabular output for each item in list macro
  \def\do##1{\bbx@tab@label{##1} & \bbx@tab@item{##1}\\}%
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \dolistloop{\blx@tempa}%
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup
  \endgroup% this closed a goup opened by \printbibtabular
}

\def\bbx@tab@label#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setdefaultrefcontext{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \blx@initsep
  \blx@namesep
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \addtocounter{instcount}\@ne
  \blx@anchor
  \csuse{bbx@tabenv@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \endgroup
}

\def\bbx@tab@item#1{%
  \begingroup
  \blx@getdata{#1}%
  \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@setoptions@entry
  \blx@thelabelnumber
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibitem}%
  \csuse{blx@item@\blx@theenv}\relax
  \blx@execute
  \blx@initunit
  \blx@beglangbib
  \bibsentence
  \blx@pagetracker
  \blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype
  \blx@postpunct
  \blx@endlangbib
  \endgroup
}

% user-level command for defining tabular bibliography format
\newrobustcmd*{\defbibtabular}[5]{%
  \long\csdef{blx@env@#1}{#2}%
  \long\csdef{blx@endenv@#1}{#3}%
  \long\csdef{bbx@tabenv@#1}{#4}%
  \long\csdef{blx@item@#1}{#5}}

\makeatother

% sortname labels (a robust style should add provision for missing labelnames)
\newbibmacro*{sortname}{%
  \DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash\break}%
  \DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}%
  \printnames[sortname]{labelname}}

% bibitem hook to suppress redundant sortname list
\newbibmacro*{omitsortname}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {}
    {\clearname{\thefield{labelnamesource}}}}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
% demo new tabular bibliography format
\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\def\arraystretch{1.5}%
   \begin{tabular}{@{}L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
                      L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}}
  {\end{tabular}}
  {\usebibmacro{sortname}}
  {\usebibmacro{omitsortname}}

% add multiline labels in default bibliography format
\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {\usebibmacro{sortname}}
     {\setlength{\labelwidth}{0.3\textwidth}%
      \setlength{\leftmargin}{\labelwidth}%
      \setlength{\labelsep}{\biblabelsep}%
      \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}%
     \renewcommand*{\makelabel}[1]{%
       \nobreak\strut\smash{\parbox[t]\labelwidth{\raggedright##1}}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\usebibmacro{omitsortname}}
  \setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}%
% ==========================================================
%
\begin{document}
%
% ==========================================================
%\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis alt,heading=bibintoc]
\printbibtabular[title=Literaturverzeichnis,heading=bibintoc]
\tableofcontents% 
% ==========================================================
Test
\footcite[399]{fs.roxin}\footcite[Wendtland][§ 240 Rn. 63]{beck.ok}\footcite[888]{jus2007.881}
%-----
\end{document}
```

[image: Three footnotes with links spanning the entire citation label minus the postnote. 1 Beckemper, FS Roxin, 397 (399). 2 BeckOK /Wendtland § 240 Rn. 63. 3 Neuner, JuS 2007, 881 (888).]