# Fake small caps & biblatex

Tags: biblatex, xetex, formatting, fontspec

I'm trying to use this answer: [Fake small caps](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225078/53779) to use fake small caps with Times New Roman in my biblatex bibliography.

For some reason I get the error message "improper alphabetic constant". 
It seems to be some problem with the rest of my document. Because the linked solution works fine on its own.

Here is my MWE:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{scrartcl}%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{lipsum}%
\usepackage[%
backend=biber,%
bibstyle=authortitle,% BIBLIOGRAPHY
citestyle=authoryear,% CITATIONS
hyperref=true,%
backref=false,%
sorting=nty,%
maxnames=99,%
isbn=false,%
block=ragged,%
dashed=false,%
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% FAKE SMALL CAPS 
\usepackage{fontspec,graphicx}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
%
%
%
\makeatletter
\newlength\fake@f
\newlength\fake@c
\def\fakesc#1{%
  \begingroup%
  \xdef\fake@name{\csname\curr@fontshape/\f@size\endcsname}%
  \fontsize{\fontdimen8\fake@name}{\baselineskip}\selectfont%
  \uppercase{#1}%
  \endgroup%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand\fauxsc[1]{\fauxschelper#1 \relax\relax}
\def\fauxschelper#1 #2\relax{%
  \fauxschelphelp#1\relax\relax%
  \if\relax#2\relax\else\ \fauxschelper#2\relax\fi%
}
\def\Hscale{.83}\def\Vscale{.72}\def\Cscale{1.00}
\def\fauxschelphelp#1#2\relax{%
  \ifnum`#1>``\ifnum`#1<`\{\scalebox{\Hscale}[\Vscale]{\uppercase{#1}}\else%
    \scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi\else\scalebox{\Cscale}[1]{#1}\fi%
  \ifx\relax#2\relax\else\fauxschelphelp#2\relax\fi}
%
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\fauxsc}% 
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
%
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@COMMENTARY{beck.ok,
    MAINTITLE       = {Beck'scher Online-Kommentar BGB},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    EDITOR          = {Bamberger, Heinz Georg and Roth, Herbert and Hau, Wolfgang and Poseck, Roman},
    SHORTHAND       = {BeckOK},
    VOLUME          = {},
    TITLE           = {},
    YEAR            = {2018},
    EDITION         = {45},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@COMMENTARY{muko.bd1,
    MAINTITLE       = {Münchener Kommentar zum Bürgerlichen Recht},
    SHORTTITLE      = {},
    SHORTHAND       = {MünchKomm},
    EDITOR          = {Säcker, Franz},
    SHORTAUTHOR     = {},
    VOLUME          = {1},
    TITLE           = {Allgemeiner Teil},
    YEAR            = {2015},
    ADDRESS         = {},
    EDITION         = {7},
    OPTIONS         = {howcited},
}

@INCOLLECTION{fs.roxin,
    AUTHOR          = {Beckemper, Katharina},
    TITLE           = {Unvernunft als Zurechnungskriterium in den „Retterfällen“},
    EDITOR          = {Manfred, Heinrich},
    BOOKTITLE       = {Strafrecht als Scientia Universalis - Festschrift f{\"u}r Claus Roxin zum 80. Geburtstag},
    SHORTTITLE      = {FS Roxin},
    YEAR            = {2011},
    PAGES           = {397--411},
    OPTIONS         = {fshowcited},
}

@ARTICLE{jus2007.881,
    author          = {Jörg Neuner},
    title           = {Was ist eine Willenserklärung?},
    journal         = {JuS},
    year            = {2007},
    pages           = {881--888},
}
%   
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
%
%
% === merged files ====
%
%
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
% biblatex.cfg
%%%
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given-bold}
\DeclareNameFormat{family-given-bold}{%
  \mkbibbold{%
    \ifgiveninits
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiveni}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:family-given}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}}
% ==========================================================
% === Titel nicht kursiv ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{citetitle}{#1}% Zitate: Schriftart der Titel
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}% Titel im LitVZ
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}%
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
%
% ==========================================================
% === kein Punkt in Library ===
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% Kein Punkt am Ende des Eintrags im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
% === Hrsg. ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat{authortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Authortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}% Editortyp in Klammern
\DeclareFieldFormat[incollection]{editortype}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat{authortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Autor
\DeclareDelimFormat{editortypedelim}{\addspace}% Kein Komma nach Editor
% ==========================================================
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addspace}%
% ==========================================================
% === Auflage/Aufl. ===
%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  edition          = {\ifbibliography{Auflage}{Aufl\adddot}},% 'Auflage' statt 'Aufl.'
}
% ==========================================================
% === kein S. bei @article & @incollection ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{pages}{%
  \ifcitation
    {\mkfirstpage{#1}}
    {#1}}%
% ==========================================================
% === Erkennt Satzzeichen & setzt kein Komma ausser bei Abkurzungen ===
%
\DefineBibliographyExtras{german}{\DeclarePunctuationPairs{comma}{*}}
% ==========================================================
% === @article keine Titel zitieren ===
%
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{citetitle}{}%
% ==========================================================
% === bei @article @incollection postnote in klammern fur seitenzahl ===
%
\AtEveryCite{%
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{postnote}{\mkbibparens{#1}}%
}

% ==========================================================
% === bib driver @commentary ===
%
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{commentary}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === @commentary prenote position === otherwise use: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430758/53779
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\footcite}[\mkbibfootnote]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{####1}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}%
     \ifentrytype{commentary}
       {\textbf{\addslash}%
        \textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
       {}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%[\mkbibcite]%
  {\ifentrytype{commentary}{}{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
     \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{####1}%
     \usebibmacro{cite}%
     \ifentrytype{commentary}
       {\textbf{\addslash}%
        \textit{\usebibmacro{prenote}}}
       {}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
% ==========================================================
% === @incollection herausgeber der festschrift nicht fett ===
%
\DeclareNameAlias{ineditor}{family-given}

\newbibmacro*{bbx:in:editor}[1]{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseeditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{editor}}
  }
    {\printnames[ineditor]{editor}%
     \setunit{\printdelim{editortypedelim}}%
     \usebibmacro{#1}%
     \clearname{editor}}
    {}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editorstrg}}
\newbibmacro*{in:editor+others}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:in:editor}{editor+othersstrg}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{incollection}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{author/translator+others}%
  \setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{in:editor+others}%<----- new macro
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
%  \usebibmacro{editor+others}% OLD
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
    {\printfield{volume}%
     \printfield{part}}
    {}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
% ==========================================================
% === Kommentare: zitiert als Option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{howcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{howcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@howcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \printfield{shorthand}%
          \setunit{\addslash}%
          \bibstring[\emph]{bearbeiter}}}}
    {}}

\NewBibliographyString{bearbeiter}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  citedas    = {zitiert als},
  bearbeiter = {Bearbeiter},
}

% ==========================================================
% === Incollection zitiert als option ===
%
\newtoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
\DeclareEntryOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}
\DeclareTypeOption[boolean]{fshowcited}[true]{\settoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}{#1}}

\newbibmacro{fshowcited}{%
  \iftoggle{tnbcbx@fshowcited}
    {\iffieldundef{shorttitle}
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \bibstring{citedas}%
          \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
          \begingroup
            \csuse{blx@hook@cite}%
            \csuse{blx@hook@citekey}%
            \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
            \printnames{labelname}%
            \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
            \printfield{shorttitle}%
          \endgroup
          }}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{\usebibmacro{howcited}\usebibmacro{fshowcited}\finentry}
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% mybiblatexcfg.tex
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
%
\renewcommand{\finentrypunct}{}% kein Punkt am Ende im LitVZ
% ==========================================================
%\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\fauxsc}% Autoren in Kapitaelchen
%==========================================================
\AtEveryCite{%
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\mkbibemph{#1}}%
}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~\textbf{/}\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}%
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{in:}{% 
  \ifentrytype{article}
  {}
  {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}
% ==========================================================
\renewbibmacro{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%}%
  \newunit}
% ==========================================================
% =========== print 'Author, Journal Year, firstpage' =========
% ======================== 09.05.18 ====================
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:journal}{%
       \newunit
       \printfield{journaltitle}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:article:pages}{%
%\newunit%\addcomma
\printfield{pages}}
%
\newbibmacro*{cite:book:shorttitle}{%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
%
\renewcommand*{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
% ========================================================
\renewbibmacro{cite}{%
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}%
    {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}%
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nonameyeardelim}}}
       {\printnames{labelname}%
        \setunit{\printdelim{nameyeardelim}}}%
     \ifentrytype{book}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}}
       {}%
     \ifentrytype{article}
       {\newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:journal}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:labeldate+extradate}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}}
       {}%
     \ifentrytype{incollection}
       {\setunit{\printdelim{nametitledelim}}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:book:shorttitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{cite:article:pages}}
       {}}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}}
%
% ==========================================================
% ==========================================================
%
\begin{document}
%
% ==========================================================
\printbibliography[title=Literaturverzeichnis alt,heading=bibintoc]
\tableofcontents% 
% ==========================================================
Test
\footcite[399]{fs.roxin}\footcite[Wendtland][§ 240 Rn. 63]{beck.ok}\footcite[888]{jus2007.881}
%-----
\end{document}
```

Any idea what went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should *either* use `fontspec` with XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX, *or* set up the legacy NFSS encodings with `fontenc` and `inputenc`, but not both. (UTF-8 input is also the default on recent versions of LaTeX.) If you’re using `fontspec`, your input and font encodings are Unicode.

Comment: @Sebastiano Yes, I've linked that specific thread in my ask.

Comment: @texnewbie Ok. I have removed my comment. Good LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. It’s an XY problem today (since Times New Roman *does* now come with small caps) but [solving it with `fontspec` and `l3kernel` was a good exercise for learning expl3.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444453/61644).

Comment: For those stumbling upon this question later: the "improper alphabetic constant" can come up because `\fauxsc` isn't desgined to read macros in general. Steven B. Segletes mentions this in a comment to his [original answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/225078/200792): *Additionally, the `\fauxsc` macro is not set up to read macros in general. If the macro expands directly to your desired text, you would use `\expandafter\fauxsc\expandafter{\foo}`, so that `\foo` is expanded to text before it is seen by `\fauxsc`*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by egreg would have worked if he hadn’t attempted to load a separate font for the small caps. Times New Roman has a small-caps feature that works just fine if you change `\fauxsc` to `\textsc`.  With recent versions of either Times New Roman (I tested 7.00) or TeX Gyre Termes, there’s no need to fake small caps at all!

The reason the small caps were not the correct weight in egreg’s answer is that the small caps fonts for upright, bold, and so forth must be specified separately (*q.v.* section 3.1 of the `fontspec` manual).

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
   SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps, Scale=MatchUppercase},
   UprightFeatures={SmallCapsFont = TeX Gyre Termes},
   BoldFeatures={SmallCapsFont = TeX Gyre Termes Bold},
   ItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont = TeX Gyre Termes Italic},
   BoldItalicFeatures={SmallCapsFont = TeX Gyre Termes Bold Italic}
]
```

As you can see, I scaled the small-caps font so its height matches.

You also need to, as egreg posted, change `\fauxsc` to `\textsc`.

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
```

I also made the following other minor changes to your document: removed the now-unused commands, removed `fontenc` and `inputenc` (`fontspec` always uses Unicode encodings anyway), and added `\usepackage{csquotes}`.

Bold small-caps now works properly and is correctly scaled:

[image: Bibliography with bold small-caps]

You’d probably also want to set the font for your captions, *e.g.* `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Scale=MatchUppercase]`.

Comment: Actually small caps in Times New Roman work at least since version 6.98. Thanks for bringing that to my attention!!!

Comment: @texnewbie The thing to worry about in some older versions of fonts that shipped with MS Windows/Office was lowercase i turning into small-caps dotted İ, as in Turkish. I originally learned how to do this trick to fix Palatino Linotype. I think that was corrected years ago, but there are still copies of Office 2003 floating around.

Answer (score 2):

Use a Times clone supporting small caps. If I change the font loading into

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}[
  SmallCapsFont=TeX Gyre Termes,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
]
```

and replace `\fauxsc` with `\textsc`,

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}
```

I get

[image]

I believe this is typographically very dubious: the whole name should be in small caps.

Comment: I thought it was common in some European styles to have a small caps family name? Perhaps I'm mistaken. I agree the bold first name looks a bit jarring in combination.

Comment: @WillRobertson The surname not showing up in the correct weight or height is an error; see my answer.

Comment: @WillRobertson By the way, great packages!

Comment: Thanks, but I've already done that. And I don't like the TeX Gyre Termes small caps mixed with Times New Roman. As asked, I really want to use Times New Roman.