# Automatically cite author's name in full the first time it appears

Tags: biblatex

It seems like there used to be a working solution but I guess it stopped working with updates to biblatex:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46469/36836

Maybe someone is able to update the solution or suggest a new one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This answer assumes `biblatex` version >= 3.4.

We will have to change the code so it complies to the new name format (cf. [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)). Furthermore I have changed the code to use name hashes instead of relying on string comparison.

The code implements a new option `nametracker`. If set to `context` names will be tracked separately for the text and footnotes, if set to `global` (or `true`) names will not be tracked separately. Of course that option can only be executed after it is defined. So in the MWE it can not be set at loading-time, it can only be set with `\ExecuteBibliographyOptions`.

```
\documentclass[british]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel,csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@nametracker@global}[1]{%
  \xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}
    {}
    {\listcsxadd{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}{#1}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@nametracker@context}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}{#1}}}
    {\xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}{#1}}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@ifnameseen@global}[1]{%
  \xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@ifnameseen@context}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}%
    {\xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}}%
    {\xifinlistcs{#1}{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}}}

\DeclareBibliographyOption[string]{nametracker}[true]{%
  \ifcsdef{blx@opt@nametracker@#1}
    {\csuse{blx@opt@nametracker@#1}}
    {\blx@err@invopt{nametracker=#1}{}}}

\def\blx@opt@nametracker@global{%
  \let\cbx@ifnameseen\cbx@ifnameseen@global
  \let\cbx@nametracker\cbx@nametracker@global}

\let\blx@opt@nametracker@true\blx@opt@nametracker@global

\def\blx@opt@nametracker@false{%
  \protected\long\def\cbx@ifnameseen##1##2##3{##3}%
  \let\cbx@nametracker\relax}

\def\blx@opt@nametracker@context{%
  \let\cbx@ifnameseen\cbx@ifnameseen@context
  \let\cbx@nametracker\cbx@nametracker@context}

\appto\blx@secinit{%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}
    {}%
  \ifcsundef{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}
    {\global\cslet{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}
    {}}

\InitializeCitationStyle{%
  \global\cslet{cbx@bseen@names@\the\c@refsection}\@empty
  \global\cslet{cbx@fseen@names@\the\c@refsection}\@empty}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{nametracker=context}

\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \cbx@ifnameseen{\thefield{hash}}
    {\ifcase\value{uniquename}%
       \usebibmacro{name:family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}%
     \or
       \ifuseprefix
         {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefix}
           {\namepartsuffixi}}
         {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
           {\namepartfamily}
           {\namepartgiveni}
           {\namepartprefixi}
           {\namepartsuffixi}}%
     \or
       \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
         {\namepartfamily}
         {\namepartgiven}
         {\namepartprefix}
         {\namepartsuffix}%
     \fi}
    {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiven}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}%
     \cbx@nametracker{\thefield{hash}}}%
    \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\cite{companion}

\cite{companion}

\cite{knuth:ct:a}

\cite{knuth:ct:b}
\end{document}
```

gives

> Michel Goossens, Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin 1994
>
> Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994
>
> Donald E. Knuth 1984
>
> Knuth 1986

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution does not play well with `style=verbose`. It always gives the full name not just the first instance in this case. I am not sure where the problem is.

Comment: @Daniel The `uniquename` feature needs to be turned on: add the option `uniquename=true` for `verbose` where it is not turned on by default (unlike for `authoryear`). Maybe you also need `\renewbibmacro*{cite:full}{%
  \usebibmacro{cite:full:citepages}%
  \printtext[bibhypertarget]{%
    \usedriver
      {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{labelname}}
      {\thefield{entrytype}}}%
  \usebibmacro{shorthandintro}}` (i.e. use `labelname` instead of `default` for `sortname` in the full citations).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding `uniquename=true` to the `biblatex` options did the trick.

Comment: @Daniel You will also need the other modification for a few corner cases, though. (Try `\cite{knuth:ct:a}` and then `\cite{knuth:ct:b}` only if you also add the second bit of code will you get to see "Knuth ..." in `knuth:ct:b`, if you don't use it you will see `Donald E. Knuth` also for `knuth:ct:b`, but maybe that is what you want.)

Comment: Thanks for the note. But it seems actually to be even trickier: since I am using citation in footnotes with the first being cited in full I want the full name in the first footnote. But when the name of the author appears before the footnote then with your fix the full name will not be output.

Comment: @Daniel Of course, the code does not track appearances in footnotes and text separately. But you can have that too. Check the edit.

Comment: Thanks again. Seems to work smoothly. I guess the "instead" in the edit refers only to the first part of the code, right?

Comment: @Daniel Correct. The `\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}` bit is the same for both.

Comment: Great feature. How can I make it work only for `\citeauthor` so the `label` will not be changed? I am thinking of a full name for the first `\citeauthor` and for the following `\citeauthor` only e.g. Initial and last name or optional only last name.

Right now it changes the label and the author’s name, too.

Comment: @LukasCB If you write `\DeclareNameFormat{citeauthor}` instead of `\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}` in my code and copy the definition of `\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeauthor}` from [the other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46469/35864) you should be good to go. If you have any trouble with that let me know (either on your github or via a new question here.)

Comment: @moewe I guess there is one other case in addition to footnotes: abstracts. I guess you want the full name in the abstract as well as in the main text when it first appears. Is that doable?

Comment: @Daniel You can reset the tracker after the abstract with `\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\cbx@fseen@names}{}\renewcommand*{\cbx@tseen@names}{}\makeatother`. If that is enough for you.

Comment: @moewe Thanks, it works! I added it in the preamble using `etoolbox`'s `\AfterEndEnvironment{abstract}{...}`.